# Sending multiple responses with the same response object in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a long running process which needs to send data back at multiple stages. Is there some way to send back multiple responses with [express.js](http://expressjs.com/)

```
res.send(200, 'hello')
res.send(200, 'world')
res.end()
```

but when I run `curl -X POST localhost:3001/helloworld` all I get is `hello`

How can I send multiple responses or is this not possible to do with express?

Comment: See the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25209269/51593. 

'You can only send one HTTP response for one HTTP request.'

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `res.write()`.

`res.send()` already makes a call to `res.end()`, meaning you can't write to res anymore after a call to res.send (meaning also your `res.end()` call was useless).

EDIT: It is a Node.js internal function. [See the documentation here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback)

Comment: I can't find that function in the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html) and it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: It is not from express, but directly from Node.js. It is the low level function. What do you try to achieve ? This should work as expected for the example you described ahead, I just tried it in local.

Comment: @aydow Links or it did not happened

Comment: @codebot, all i can see from the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) is that `res.write()` is not there

Comment: @aydow `res.write()` is a Node.js function, [see the documentation here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback)

Comment: thanks for the clarification, guys. apologies for the confusion!

Comment: Why can't I write `res.json()` multiple times instead of `res.write()` in **express** ?

As I want to send multiple responses as in a json format from the same api request.

Comment: How to handle multiple response in front-end part.

Comment: @aydow `res.write()` isn't deprecated. I suggest removing your comment lest it mislead someone.

Comment: @aakash4dev I have an example of streaming server-sent events from a client in [How to use server-sent-events in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67184841/6243352).

Answer (score 8):

You can only send one HTTP response for one HTTP request. However, you can certainly write whatever kind of data in the response that you want. That could be newline-delimited JSON, multipart parts, or whatever other format you choose.

If you want to stream events from the server to the browser, an easy alternative might be to use something like [Server-sent events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) ([polyfill](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource)).

Comment: I think this should really be the accepted answer. The main point, as you say, is that 'You can only send one HTTP response for one HTTP request.' I think the questioner is asking for something like streaming, rather than the ability to `write()` repeatedly before calling `send()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this should solve your problem.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  var i = 1,
    max = 5;

  //set the appropriate HTTP header
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

  //send multiple responses to the client
  for (; i <= max; i++) {
    res.write('<h1>This is the response #: ' + i + '</h1>');
  }

  //end the response process
  res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
res.write(JSON.stringify({
    min, 
    max, 
    formattedData
}));
```

or

```js
res.send({
    min,
    max,
    formattedData
});
```

refer [Node Res.write send multiple objects:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52223175/node-res-write-send-multiple-objects)