# Integrate Server-sent events in NodeJs Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-sent-events

Hi I want my server to send data to the client. For now I want to count down from 10 till 0 and then disconnect. I want to use SSE because I only need it to be unidirectional.

I'm using nodejs with express.

I found this thread on stackoverflow that got me in the right direction but im stuck so im here for a helping hand. This is the thread:  [How to use server-sent-events in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657222/how-to-use-server-sent-events-in-express-js)

This Is what i got:

Routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');

/* GET home page. */

const myHtml = fs.readFileSync('./views/price/changes/24hours.html', 'utf-8');
const price_24h_apidata = fs.readFileSync("./apidata/price/apidata_price_24h_changes.json", 'utf-8');

function countdown(res, count) {
  res.write("data: " + count + "\n\n")
  if (count)
    //Placeholder: later update, jsonapidata
    setTimeout(() => countdown(res, count-1), 1000)
  else
    res.end()
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.send(myHtml.replace(/jsonapidata/g, JSON.stringify(({price_24h_apidata}), null, 0)));

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  })

  countdown(res, 10)

});

module.exports = router;
```

code included in the HTML Page:

```
  <script>
    if (!!window.EventSource) {
      var source = new EventSource('/price/changes/24hour');

      source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = e.data
      }, false)

      source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
        document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = "Connected"
      }, false)

      source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        const id_state = document.getElementById('state')
        if (e.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED)
          source.close()
        if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
          id_state.innerHTML = "Disconnected"
        }
        else if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CONNECTING) {
          id_state.innerHTML = "Connecting..."
        }
      }, false)
    } else {
      console.log("Your browser doesn't support SSE")
    }
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
  var unparseddata = (jsonapidata);
  var apidata =  JSON.parse(unparseddata.price_24h_apidata);
</script>

<div class="test1">
  <h1>SSE: <span id="state"></span></h1>
  <h3>Data: <span id="data"></span></h3>
</div>
```

When running the server there is no error. When visiting the page I'm receiving this error:

```
GET /price/changes/24hour 200 24.501 ms - -
Error: Cannot find module 'html'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at new View (C:\Users\Feds\Documents\Coinparticle\coinparticle\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Feds\Documents\Coinparticle\coinparticle\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Feds\Documents\Coinparticle\coinparticle\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\Users\Feds\Documents\Coinparticle\coinparticle\app.js:70:7
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\Feds\Documents\Coinparticle\coinparticle\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a long polling function on the front end which `get`s the data from the nodejs application? You can do it in a interval as well.

Comment: @ZombieChowder I just need the dataflow just to be one way