# Get partially response from node js api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

I want to get a response from node js API to client-side on every step the API completes till API completes its full step.

Suppose I call **localhost/api/doStepCompleate** on my backend(Node js) API will complete multiple steps but want to send every step response to the client-side till the API completes its full task.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this is an http request/response, then you can use `res.write()` on the server to send partial responses and finally call `res.end()` when you're done.

A challenge here will be that many clients are not set up to process partial responses.  Libraries such as `fetch()` will wait for the entire response and not notify their caller of partial responses unless you configure the response as a stream and you have client-side code to parse arbitrary chunks of data as it arrives.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62121310/how-to-handle-streaming-data-using-fetch) for some idea how that can work.